# .vimrc autocommand if NOT filetype

Tags: vim, autocommand

I have a master .vimrc that sets up my global working environment, including special setup for both C++ and Python filetypes.

In a project folder I have an .exrc with project-specific settings for C++, but this is overriding my master .vimrc settings for Python.

How can I create an autocommand that sets these options only if it is not a python file? I don't want to wrap the project C++ settings in an autocommand because we have multiple source file types and that means a lot of duplicated code in .vimrc as well as the potential to miss a file type.

What I really want is a construct like this:

```
if Filetype python then
   ...
else
   ...
endif
```

But it would be sufficient to simply do this:

```
if not Filetype python then ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if &filetype != 'python'
```

[`&filetype`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-option) gets the value of the current [file type](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html).